# Cómo hago para que una etiqueta H1 no bloquee un evento de un DIV posicionado justo debajo

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventos

Actualmente tengo un `div` con una imagen que cuando haces hover, ésta se cambia por otra imagen. Después, por otra parte, tengo una etiqueta `h1` posicionada justo encima de la imagen y al pasar por encima de esta me bloquea el evento hover del `div` que contiene la imagen.

¿Existe alguna forma de solucionar esto?

Comment: Estoy con @Mariano, si publicas el código será mas fácil ayudarte y que no te cierren la pregunta

Comment: Me parece que este problema se entiende mejor con prosa que usando código. Salvo que sea un snippet que lo pruebe ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Después, por otra parte, tengo una etiqueta h1 posicionada justo encima de la imagen y al pasar por encima de esta me bloquea el evento `hover` del `<div>` que contiene la imagen.

No es necesario utilizar jQuery ni javascript, esto puede hacerse por CSS directamente.

Utilizando [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) en el `<h1>`.

De esta forma, el `<h1>` se vuelve "transparente" a los eventos del ratón, como si no estuviera.

Ejemplo.

```css
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  /* esto lo hace transparente */
  pointer-events: none;
}


img:hover {
   border: 4px solid red; 
}
```

```html
<img src="//placehold.it/100x100">
<h1>Hola SOes</h1>
```

Si quieres hacerlo con javascript o jQuery, es lo mismo, pero activado por código, aunque en tu caso, si el efecto debe ser permanente, la mejor solución es ponerlo via CSS y listo. Por las dudas te dejo unos ejemplos:

#### Via Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('idDelH1').style.pointerEvents = 'none';
```

#### Via jQuery:

```
$('#idDelH1').css('pointer-events', 'none');
```

Comment: Genial!! Muchisimas gracias!! Era justo lo que necesitaba. Un saludo.

Comment: @Alonso recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta que te sirvio. Salu2

Comment: @Alonso Si esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, por favor considera aceptarla haciendo click en el **✅** a la izquierda de la misma (ambos se benefician). Más información: [¿Qué significa cuando una respuesta es "aceptada"?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: mariano, tus templates van evolucionando.. 